# If $R$ and $s$ are the range and standard deviation of a set of $n$ values, then $4\le R^2/s^2\le 2n$

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

> **Problem**
>
> Let $R$ and $s$ be respectively the range and [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) , respectively, of a set of $n$ values. Then prove that $\dfrac{R^2}{2n}\leq s^2\leq \dfrac{R^2}{4}$.

I have tried using the definition of range and standard deviation but neither of the inequality can be proved. Can anyone help me in proving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality (by translation), assume that the data is such that $0\leq x_i\leq R$, with the smallest data $x_{\min}=0$, and the largest data is $x_{\max}=R$. Let $\mu$ be the mean. Then
$$\sum_i x_i^2 = \sum_i x_ix_i \leq \sum_i Rx_i= nR\mu$$
Also note that $\mu\leq R$. Therefore,
$$ns^2= \sum_i (x_i-\mu)^2 = \sum_i x_i^2 -n\mu^2  \leq nR\mu-n\mu^2 =n\mu(R-\mu)\leq nR^2/4.$$
So, $s^2\leq R^2/4$.

For the lower bound, note that
$$2ns^2= 2\sum_i (x_i-\mu)^2 \geq 2[(x_{\max}-\mu)^2+ (x_{\min}-\mu)^2]=2[(R-\mu)^2+\mu^2]\geq R^2,$$
where the last inequality follows from arithmetic-quadratic mean inequality, which is
$$\frac{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2}{n} \geq \left(\frac{x_1+\ldots+x_n}{n}\right)^2$$ applied to $(R-\mu)$ and $\mu$.
Therefore, $s^2\geq R^2/2n$, and so this completes the proof.

Comment: I could not solve this because I did not assume all data were positive. How does that wlog work exactly?

Comment: @futurebird Translating the data (adding all the data by the same constant) does not affect both variance and range. Say if the data is from $a$ to $a+R$, we could add $-a$ to all of them so that $0\leq x_i\leq R$ and the variance and the range will stay the same. This will not change the result.